# Facing the issue ZAP Browser launch Issue

Tags: zap

We are trying to evaluate ZAP for our application. However, whenever we are running Automated Scan or even ... using Chrome, it shows a pop up saying: "Failed to start Chrome browser. Make sure that Chrome and ChromeDriver are available. For more details refer to the "Options Selenium screen" help page. I am using version 2.10.0. Even I am following the same step and I have updated the chrome version as well (Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)) but still no luck.

Kindly help us so that we can continue our process to evaluate ZAP for our application smoothly.

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking this on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: The ZAP core team monitors the "zap" tag here so tbh this is better. The ZAP User Group would be even better then here of course :D https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked for ZAP updates? We have released a new version of the Chrome webdrivers very recently - you need to keep those up to date.

Comment: I have checked the same but ZAP is up to date (2.10.0) and My LInux WebDrivers version 28.0.0 and Selenium version is 15.3.0

Comment: What version of Chrome do you have installed? Is it on the path? Are there any errors in the zap.log file? https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/somethings-not-working-what-should-i-do/#check-the-log-file

Comment: Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (64-bit). I installed

Comment: As per https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/linux-webdrivers/ the latest Linux Drivers support Chrome 90. Can you update chrome? If not you can try installing the older drivers manually https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/releases/tag/webdriverlinux-v26

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue on ZAP while using automated scan for my application.
The issue got solved when I update my chrome driver to the version supported by the Windows WebDrivers addons of ZAP.

Always make sure whether your chrome driver version is supported by ZAP.
 You can check the supported chrome driver version under Help -> Check for updates -> Installed -> Windows WebDrivers on ZAP.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UokO.png
If you have not installed Windows WebDrivers addons, then you have install it under MarketPlace and check for the supported version.
You can check your chrome driver version using chrome://settings/help on chrome browser.

[owasp](/questions/tagged/owasp)[zap](/questions/tagged/zap)[chromebrowser](/questions/tagged/chromebrowser)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if your are on `sudo`, browser does open. In my case, I rebooted and started `zaproxy` without sudo successfully.